# Magento 2.2.3 Checkout page loader doesn't complete loading

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

[image]

Magento 2.2.3 checkout page is loading infinitely. I have checked the view source and it seems something stopped the js loading. I have checked many threads relating this and nowhere found a solution.

```
<div id="checkout" data-bind="scope:'checkout'" class="checkout-container">
    <div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="https://www.domain.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/loader-1.gif"
                 alt="Loading..."
                 style="position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#checkout": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":
```

Comment: Anything in the error console of your browser? Seems like a library that is not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think this is the solution for this particular case.

First of all check in console. A error might appear like,
"**Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals::setExtensionAttributes() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsExtensionInterface, instance of Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtension given, called in /htdocs/magento2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php on line 125 and defined in /htdocs/magento2.2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/Totals.php:592**"

I debugged for quite a while and come to the following solution.

- Need to override **Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository**

For that, add following in Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote\CartTotalRepository" />
```

- Create CartTotalRepository.php at the path Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote\CartTotalRepository.php

Paste the following code in CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Rewrite\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Api;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;

/*Added below two lines*/
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\TotalsConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;

/**
 * Cart totals data object.
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CartTotalRepository extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * Cart totals factory.
     *
     * @var Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $totalsFactory;

    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    private $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var ConfigurationPool
     */
    private $itemConverter;

    /**
     * @var CouponManagementInterface
     */
    protected $couponService;

    /**
     * @var TotalsConverter
     */
    protected $totalsConverter;

    /**
     * @param Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory $totalsFactory
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param CouponManagementInterface $couponService
     * @param TotalsConverter $totalsConverter
     * @param ItemConverter $converter
     */
    public function __construct(
        Api\Data\TotalsInterfaceFactory $totalsFactory,
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        CouponManagementInterface $couponService,
        TotalsConverter $totalsConverter,
        ItemConverter $converter
    ) {
        $this->totalsFactory = $totalsFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->couponService = $couponService;
        $this->totalsConverter = $totalsConverter;
        $this->itemConverter = $converter;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @param int $cartId The cart ID.
     * @return Totals Quote totals data.
     */
    public function get($cartId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
            $addressTotalsData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
            $addressTotals = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getTotals();
        } else {
            $addressTotalsData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
            $addressTotals = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getTotals();
        }
        //Added New Line Here
        unset($addressTotalsData[ExtensibleDataInterface::EXTENSION_ATTRIBUTES_KEY]);
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface $quoteTotals */
        $quoteTotals = $this->totalsFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $quoteTotals,
            $addressTotalsData,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface::class
        );
        $items = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $index => $item) {
            $items[$index] = $this->itemConverter->modelToDataObject($item);
        }
        $calculatedTotals = $this->totalsConverter->process($addressTotals);
        $quoteTotals->setTotalSegments($calculatedTotals);

        $amount = $quoteTotals->getGrandTotal() - $quoteTotals->getTaxAmount();
        $amount = $amount > 0 ? $amount : 0;
        $quoteTotals->setCouponCode($this->couponService->get($cartId));
        $quoteTotals->setGrandTotal($amount);
        $quoteTotals->setItems($items);
        $quoteTotals->setItemsQty($quote->getItemsQty());
        $quoteTotals->setBaseCurrencyCode($quote->getBaseCurrencyCode());
        $quoteTotals->setQuoteCurrencyCode($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode());
        return $quoteTotals;
    }
}
```

I have made 2 modifications in the file.
1. Simply added 2 lines on line number 17 & 18.
2. Added 1 line on line number 102.

Comment: It's working properly.